# How do I provide the latest value of a hot observable on subscribe

Tags: system.reactive

I have a hot observable (from an event) that I'm calling `DistinctUntilChanged` on which will have multiple subscribers who will subscribe at different times after the observable has started running and produced its first value. Subscribers will get getting the `IObservable` through a property on my class.

How do I make it so that each time someone subscribes to the observable they get the last value published but the observable acts normally otherwise? I think I might be looking for `PublishLast` but I'm not sure if it has other side effects.

**Similar question**: [How do I get an IObservable to push the newest value upon subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173081)? This is a very similar question but it's from over a year ago and a lot of additions have been made to Rx so I think there might be a built-in function now rather than having to rely on a `BehaviorSubject` so I don't think this is an exact duplicate.

**Edit:** [Here is](https://github.com/Aesir/ObservableKinect/commit/3dd1b11424d6460b2b1364d198cf54201e703390#diff-2) what I'm actually trying to do. There's a comment below the actual observable sequence I'm talking about.

Comment: Can you clarify why `Publish` and the `BehaviorSubject` from the linked question aren't "built-in" enough?  They do precisely what you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other answer was close. You either want a ReplaySubject(1) ie only replay 1 value; or you want a BehaviorSubject. The difference is a Behavior Subject will require a default value. This will also guarantee that the subscriber will always get a value immediately.

```
var replay1 = source.Replay(1);
replay1.Connect();
//Or
var alwaysHaveValue = source.Multicast(new BehaviorSubject<int>(-1));
```

To understand each of the Subjects check out my [Intro to Rx](http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2010/05/intro-to-rx.html) post